# HP ProCurve switch off weak ciphers - disable SSH CBC Mode Ciphers and RC4

Tags: security, hp, hp-procurve, ssh

Is there any option for HP switches to change/modify used ssh ciphers?
For exmaple in cisco we can issue commands:

```
ip ssh server algorithm encryption aes256-ctr
ip ssh server algorithm mac hmac-sha1
```

I couldn't find anything which would achive same results in HP Procurve documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set this with:

```
ip ssh cipher aes-256-ctr
ip ssh mac hmac-sha1
```

You may also have to disable the other algorithms first using the no forms of the commands.